# SessionScope variable in for loop

Tags: xpages

I am trying to apply for loop in the xpages application.

In the computed field, I put the following code and it shows the result as expected.

```
var msg = "";

for(var j = 1; j <5;j++)
{
    msg += "* This message is from  " +j +" " ;
}
return msg;

//Result will show something like this
//"* This message is from 1 * This message is from 2 * This message is from 3 * This message is from 4 * This message is from 5 "
```

Assume in page A there is a multiline edit box, it uses sessionScope variable (ssvTopic). In pages B there is a computed field, I can show the values from the multiline edit box by use this code

```
sessionScope.ssvTopic
```

This works fine. Now I try to apply the sessionScope variable in the for loop.

```
var msg ="";
var value = sessionScope.ssvTopic

for(var i =0; i< value.length; i++)
{
    msg += "* This message is from  " + value+" " ;
}
return msg;
```

When I run the application, I notice the value.length means the number of characters in value. I mean if the sessionScope.ssvTopic values are life style, news, sports, the characters are 24, so the in the for loop, the message will display 24 times.

So I change the code value.length to @Count(value). When I run the application, the message only display one time.

```
var msg ="";
var value = sessionScope.ssvTopic

for(var i =0; i< @Count(value); i++)
{
    msg += "* This message is from  " + value+" " ;
}
return msg;

//The result display like this, it only display one time
//* This message is from life style, news, sports
```

I think @Count(value) is close to the result (compare with value.length), but I don't understand why it  shows the message one time only.

I also try to put the sessionScope value in a array, but the result is the same, it just shows one message.

```
var msg ="";
var value = sessionScope.ssvTopic
var valueArray = new Array();

viewScope.put("valueArray", @Implode(valueArray, ",")) ;
valueArray.push(value);

//no matter if I use @Count(valueArray) or valueArray.length, the result does not have difference
for(var i =0; i< @Count(valueArray); i++) 
{
    msg += "* This message is from  " + valueArray+" " ; //no matter if I use valueArray or valueArray[i], the result does not have difference too
}
return msg;
```

I am not sure which part I  make mistake. What I intend to do is to show the number of messages depends on the number of the sessionScope variable values. In my case if the sessionScope variable contains life style, news, sports, the result will be someting like this

```
* This message is from life style * This message is from news * This messages is from sports
```

If I run this code again, it works fine.

```
var msg = "";

for(var j = 1; j <5;j++)
{
    msg += "* This message is from  " +j +" " ;
}
return msg;
```

So I just change the "5" to sessionScope variable, it will not show the number of messages depends on the number of the sessionScope variable values.

Would someone let me know how to solve this issue. Thanks a lot.

**(A quick update)**

I try the following the code but it does not return anything.

```
 for(var i =0; i< sessionScope.ssvTopic; i++) 
{
    msg += "* This message is from  " + ssvTopic[i]+" " ;  // with [i] or without [i], the result is the same, it does not return anything
}
return msg;
```

Instead of return the message, I try to return other things  such @Count(value), @Count(valuArray), valueArray.length.

```
@Count(value) //this returns 1.0
@Count(valueArray) //this returns 1.0
valueArray.length //this returns 1.0
value.length //this return 24.0 as mentioned above, this returns the number of characters of the value
```

Therefore I notice this a mistake in the code, but I don't understand the The mistake only return 1.0 for the result.

Comment: Perhaps the solution for this issue is not that difficult, I visit this [website](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) and I am still not very sure which part I make mistake in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed only a little thing to get it to work:

```js
var msg = "";
var value = sessionScope.ssvTopic.split('\n');

for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    msg += "* This message is from  " + value[i] + " " ;
}
return msg;
```

Multiline edit box returns a multi-line string, not an array of strings.  So, you need to [**split**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) the string by newline first. Then you can work with the resulting array.

(@Count always returned *1* as multiline edit box's value was only *one* string)

Comment: Thanks your answer. I put the .split('\n') in the code and run the program. The message shows only one message. Currently, the multi-line edit box has the sessionScope variable only, it does not contain other code. So do I also need to put .split('\n')  in the multi-line box to make for loop work?

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, the code works fine. I just open the other multi-line edit box accidentally. The answer is accepted. Thank you very for your help and let me know that I can use split in xpages.